# PXE Boot Problems /cdrom access denied

Tags: boot, server, nfs, pxe

I am having issues with trying to PXE boot the latest Ubuntu 15.04 MATE image. I have mounted the ISO and copied the files to `/tftpboot/nfs/ubuntu/`

I am using `syslinux`, and followed this tutorial: http://it-joe.com/howtos/pxe.php

My aim is to make a portable Raspberry Pi PXE server.

I cannot boot the system, I get past syslinux, and the system begins to boot, I even see the Ubuntu Mate splash screen.

The issue is that when I press the arrow keys to view the verbose output, the system hangs at:

> /cdrom access denied

The syslog of the server says that:

> "/" is not exported.

I have tried with some success to use the `initrd.lz` from netboot image, but this just wants to download from archive.ubuntu.com, but I already have all the install files!

If you could help, great. Thanks!